# What is the use of unapply in this sample Play framework code (Form mapping)

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm new to Play framework and going over the 2.1 [samples](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.1-RC3/Samples), and in the `computer-database` example, I've found the following form definition that I don't fully understand.

What is the role of `Computer.apply` and `Computer.unapply` here?

```
  val computerForm = Form(
    mapping(
      "id" -> ignored(NotAssigned:Pk[Long]),
      "name" -> nonEmptyText,
      "introduced" -> optional(date("yyyy-MM-dd")),
      "discontinued" -> optional(date("yyyy-MM-dd")),
      "company" -> optional(longNumber)
    )(Computer.apply)(Computer.unapply)
  )
```

(from `controllers/Application.scala`)

**EDIT**: this seems to be a good resource: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/play-framework/dxNQ8E81YJs but still not sure I fully get the big picture.

Comment: I could understand the usage of `apply` in the first parameter, but when the second parameter  unapply  will be used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a common pattern in Play when you want to bind a form to the fields of a case class (in this case `Computer`).

The `mapping` method allows you to provide the construction and deconstruction functions that will be called to populate the form and extract data from it.

Since here you want to go to/from `Computer`, you need a method that creates a `Computer` from parameters, and one that extract parameters from a `Computer`, and that's exactly `Computer.apply` and `Computer.unapply`.

Related example: the mapping example in the [Play documentation on forms](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.1-RC3/ScalaForms).

Comment: Could you please point to an example on how to use the unapply method? I've only ever seen apply being used (indirectly by noticing that a Computer gets created,) I've never seen a Computer -> Form translation.

Comment: @user247077: you don't usually call `unapply` directly yourself, but actually, you probably use it everyday without knowing it, in pattern matching! See for example http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/11/21/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-1-extractors.html and http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/extractor-objects.html.

Answer (score 5):

You should learn what are apply/unapply in the Scala context, because it's not specific to Play2/forms.

- [A Tour of Scala: Extractor Objects](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/112)
- [Scala extractors](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/scala_extractors.htm)

> In the apply method we take the required parameters and return the new
>   instance of class we are interested in where as we do the reverse in
>   unapply- we take the instance and extract out the required information
>   and return them in the form of a tuple.

In a nutshell: `apply` is used to construct Computer object from parameters. `unapply` is used for the opposite case, extract parameters from the Computer object.